# Communicating between qt application and erlang server via erlang port

Tags: c++, qt, erlang, erlang-ports

I need to make a client (qt c++) and a server (erlang) in ubuntu.
The server should be a generic OTP server.
Client should connect to server and send some data (string) and erlang srv should return the same string.

Please suggest me a example code or a skeleton to implement this things.

I decided to start with this:

```
connect(Message) ->
    Cmd = "./myqtwindowapp \n",
    Port = open_port({spawn,Cmd}, [stream,use_stdio,exit_status]),
    Payload = string:concat(Message, "\n"),
    erlang:port_command(Port, Payload),
    receive
        {Port, {data, Data}} ->
            ?DBG("Received data: ~p~n", [Data]);
        Other ->
            io:format("Unexpected data: ~p~n", [Other]);
        after 15000 ->
            ?DBG("Received nothing~n", [])
    end.
```

Please help me with the client and the server.

Comment: Why don't your current code work? What do you want it to do and what does it do instead?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to use a port command for this? Why not a tcp port (see gen_tcp)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use some IPC to make the communication. You can open a socket ([gen_tcp](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html)) or use [D-Bus](https://code.google.com/p/erlang-dbus/) for instance. Qt also have proper classes to handle sockets and d-bus.